# Set item to complete 2 levels deep in Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Been trying to figure this out for a few hours now...
How do I set the complete to toggle in Notes inside the Task object?

Am I approaching this right?

Reducer:

```
let taskReducer = function(tasks = [], action) {
    case 'COMPLETE_NOTE':
      return tasks.map((task) => {
          if(action.taskId !== task.id) {
            return task;
          } else if(action.taskId === task.id) {
            const { notes } = task;
            notes.map((note) => {
              return note.id === action.noteId ?
                Object.assign({}, note, {note: {completed: !note.completed}}): note
            })
          }
        })
default:
      return tasks;
  }
}
```

Actions:

```
let actions = {
  completeNote: (taskId, noteId) => {
    return {
      type: 'COMPLETE_NOTE',
      taskId: taskId,
      noteId: noteId,
    }
  }
}
```

Client:

```
let initialState = {
  tasks: [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'do this',
    completed: false,
    notes: [{
      id: 0,
      title: 'note1',
      completed: false
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've pretty much found a way to make it work. As long as each note is associated with exactly one task and this code isn't creating a performance bottleneck, I'd probably just stick with the solution you've worked up. If you'd like, I can elaborate on either of those potential problems, but I think your approach would work just fine for a simple todo app.

**Edit**

Having read your comment, I see now that you're trying to work out a bug and not just asking if there's a "better way". Sorry for reading too quickly. Anyway, to fix the problem, you'll want to return the task in your `elseif` block. For example:

```
else if(action.taskId === task.id) {
  const { notes } = task;
  return {
    ...task,
    notes: notes.map((note) => {
      return note.id !== action.noteId ? note : {
        ...note,
        completed: !note.completed
      };
    })
  };
}

// Without using spread operator

else if(action.taskId === task.id) {
  const { notes } = task;
  return Object.assign({}, task, {
    notes: notes.map((note) => {
      return note.id !== action.noteId ? note : Object.assign({}, note, {
        completed: !note.completed
      })
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I'd like to keep it simple. After it goes through the reducer for COMPLETE_NOTE, the task itself becomes undefined. What do you suggest my code to like?

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed your problem. Inside the body of the elseif block, you should return the task with the modified notes property. Check the edit in my response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No worries, I could've been clearer. Anyways, it doesn't seem to be liking the spread operator after the first return?

Comment: It seems to be adding a new property of task into the Object and a new property of note into it setting it to be true. lol

Comment: Sorry, check the code block in the edit again. I've scrutinized the logic a bit more closely. This should work now.

Comment: It's still not liking the spread operators for some reason...?

Comment: Just demonstrated how to do it using `Object.assign` instead of the spread operator.

Comment: YESsssss! That one makes more sense to me. Thank you Brandon!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

First of all, instead of an array of tasks, I suggest you create an object where the todos are mapped by their ids. The same for the notes. So your state object would look like:

```
tasks: {
    "uniqueid1": {
        title: "some task",
        completed: false,
        notes: {
            "noteid1": {
                title: "some note",
                completed: false
            }
        }
    },
    "uniqueid2": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Then create a reducer for each part of the todo and note and use the `combineReducers` function to create a task object. So in your code you would have something like this:

```
const task = combineReducers({
    title: taskTitle,  // taskTitle is a reducer
    completed: taskCompleted,  //taskCompleted is a reducer
    notes
});

// example implementation of the notes reducer:
const notes = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_NOTE_TITLE':
        case 'COMPLETE_NOTE':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.noteId]: note(state[action.noteId], action)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const note = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'COMPLETE_NOTE':
            return {
                ...state,
                completed: true
            };
        case 'CHANGE_NOTE_TITLE':
            return {
                ...state,
                title: action.newTitle
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
// note that you could split *note* into *title* and *completed* reducers
// and use the combineReducers function again
```

One of the basic ideas of Redux is that you have many reducers and each of them takes care of only a small part of the whole state. This nicely separates concerns and makes code easier to maintain.

I suggest you [watch Dan Abramov's (the author of Redux) free course Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) where he talks about all this stuff.